# 2nd order perturbation of a charged rotating body

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

What is the 2nd order perturbation to the flat Minkowski metric $\eta_{ab}$ caused by a charged, rotating body? In particular, if we take a metric $\eta_{ab} + h_{ab} $, what $h_{ab}$ satisfies the Einstein equations for a source of mass $\epsilon m$ and charge $\epsilon e$ up to second order in $\epsilon$?

I know that the second order perturbation by a charged, non-rotating body is given by

$u_{ab}=\frac{1}{2r^2} \left[ (3m^2 -q^2)\eta_{ab} -(m^2 +3e^2)\nabla_a t \nabla_b t\right]$
(see eqn 61 here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04359)

[where the first order perturbation is

$h_{ab}=\frac{2M}{r}(\eta_{ab}+2\nabla_a t \nabla_b t)$

and we are working in spherical coordinates]

but what is the equivalent formulation when rotation is included? Or even for a rotating but uncharged mass?

Further detail - I'm looking for something like eqn (3) and (4)
[here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.04264)
but (without necessarily including the quadrupole moment $q$) with non-zero charge $e$.

Comment: Second order in what? What are you expanding about? Flat space?

Comment: Yes, around flat space.

Comment: Still, second order in what? You need to have a small parameter, right?

Comment: Second order in either the mass or the charge, as in the example above

Comment: So you just want expand the Kerr-Newman solution in mass and charge?

Comment: From the above paper: "Consider for example a family of spherically-symmetric bodies with masses εm and electric charges εq. The stress-energy tensors associated with these systems are quadratic in the electromagnetic field, and therefore quadratic in ε." I would like a similar result but for a rotating body. 

The pdf of the paper can be found here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.04359.pdf

Answer (score 1):

One particularly simple example of a field of a rotating charged object is the [Kerr-Newman metric in Kerr-Schild coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr%E2%80%93Newman_metric#Alternative_(Kerr%E2%80%93Schild)_formulation) (see also [Scholarpedia entry](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Kerr-Newman_metric#Kerr-Schild_coordinates)). This is an exact solution to Einstein equations and if you do not assume anything about the magnitude of the black hole angular momentum, the Kerr-Schild form gives you what you are looking for (if you assume angular momentum$\sim \epsilon$, you can just expand the expressions to second order in $a$).

However, notice that the Kerr-Schild expression will not agree with what you have in the OP when $a=0$. This is because you have not specified your coordinates or equivalently gauge conditions on $h^{\mu\nu}$. Whether this matters depends really on the application you are looking for.

An additional point to consider is the fact that the second-order perturbation is *not* the general external field of a rotating body because a general rotating body will have a different quadrupole (the $\sim a^2$ term). In fact, any finite body made of ordinary matter will have a *larger* quadrupole at given $a$. You can use the appropriately expanded Manko et al. metric discussed in the paper ["An all-purpose metric for the exterior of any kind of rotating neutron star" by Pappas & Apostolatos (2013)](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/429/4/3007/1010921) for the exterior of a generic rotating object.

Comment: Expanding Kerr-Newman to second order isn't what I was looking for - just as the first order post-Minkowski approximation to the Kerr metric is different to the Kerr metric. I am looking for an equivalent (a second order post-Minkowski approximation) for the Kerr-Newman metric. See the text above (65) in that paper for more details - hope that makes it clearer!

As for gauge conditions, I haven't imposed any on $h_{ab}$ and the coordinate system could be Cartesian, spherical or use the complex-translated radial coordinate given in (72).

Comment: @supercoolphysicist When you have a metric to linear order in $\epsilon$, you can impose a near-identity coordinate transform $x^\mu \to x^\mu + \xi^\mu$ ($\xi^\mu \sim \epsilon$) while keeping the metric still linearly close to Minkowski. Then the deviation from the Minkowski metric transforms as $h_{\mu\nu} \to h'_{\mu\nu} = h_{\mu\nu} + \xi_{\mu,\nu} + \xi_{\nu,\mu}$. This coordinate transform can be viewed as a "gauge transform" of the field $h_{\mu\nu}$, and the freedom of the choice of coordinates (gauge) can be partially fixed by conditions on the total deviation $h'_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: are you saying I should transform the Kerr-Newman solution using a Lie derivative transform?

Comment: @supercoolphysicist No, I am saying you have to specify the gauge of the post-Minkowski theory you are talking about (in the second order theory it starts to be more meaningful to talk about the gauge conditions as conditions on coordinates). The Kerr-Schild form of Kerr-Newman is certainly a second-order (and in fact any-order) post-Minkowskian solution in *some* gauge. Harte & Vines are implicitly using the Lorentz gauge, I believe, and use the isotropic coordinates for their field to second-order in mass and charge - but there is no such "nice" choice once you break spherical symmetry.

Comment: Ok, so what gauge should I use to make it second order? Or maybe it would be better to ask what the stress-energy tensor is for a rotating charged body to second order?

Comment: @supercoolphysicist There is not a whole lot of second order post-Minkowski computations out there, so there is no "dominant" approach. You could assume Lorentz gauge for every new piece  of the perturbation, $\nabla_{\mu}^{(n-1)}\bar{h}^{\mu\nu}_{(n)} = 0$, where $\nabla^{(n-1)}$ is covariant with respect to the metric to order $\epsilon^{n-1}$ and $\bar{h}$ the trace-reversed perturbation. Or you could expand the [harmonic coordinate condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_coordinate_condition) and get a tower of gauge conditions by requiring it applies at every order.